# In Azure Devops, how can I create a branch policy to require linked work items be resolved before a PR is merged?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, pull-request

My QA team has asked me to prevent pull requests from being merged until the associated work items have been marked as resolved (meaning the testing did not discover defects.) I already require that a member of their team approves the PR, but they are concerned about someone accidentally approving the wrong PR before it's ready. They also would like this to be automated since they are already manually managing the work items. I can't say I disagree with their wishes.

There is a similar option to automatically close linked work items when the PR is merged, but this seems backwards to me - I can't merge the changes into the next release until the work items are resolved and properly documented.

I checked the built-in branch policies, and none of them meet my requirements. The closest option is to require work items to be linked, but this alone does not prevent merging before testing is completed.

Is what they're asking for an acceptable use of branch policies? Or is our workflow just incompatible with this platform?

Comment: Git literally can't do this, as it doesn't even have PRs. Azure Devops possibly can, because it adds the concept of a pull request. You'll need to set something up via Azure. I have no experience with Azure, but on GitHub, which also adds PRs to Git, you'd do this by controlling who is allowed to push to and merge into particular branch names. That's not as automated as you asked for. GitHub have some additional automation you can enable but I leave that to GitHub experts, and here you need Azure experts instead.

Comment: Hi coavins, I have updated my answer and share the method to validate the pr with your target wit state. You could test it in your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated on 12/19**

For this scenario that you would like to validate the pull request with the specific work item state. I suppose that you could add a branch policy of `Build Validation`.

[image]

You could add the ps script below in `powershell task` to check the work-item state linking to your target pr.

```
# Define organization base url, PAT, linked wit, Target WIT state and API version variables
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{yourORG}/{yourPROJECT}"
$pat = ""
$queryString = "fields=system.state&api-version=7.0"
$witID = {YourWitID} 
$TargetState = {yourWITstateForPRapproval}

# Create header with PAT
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

# Get the linked wit state
$projectsUrl = "$orgUrl/_apis/wit/workitems/$witID?$queryString"
$field = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fields

write-host $field

$witstate = $field.'System.State'

Write-Host $witstate

#Compare the wit state with target approval state

if ($witstate -eq "$TargetState" ) {
    Write-Host "Check Succeeded"
}
else {
    Write-Host ("Check Failed")
    exit 1
}
```

Only when the build succeeds, your pr could be complete.

==============================================================

I suppose that you could check the setting for [Check for linked work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#check-for-linked-work-items).

You could set the policy with screenshots below. And you could also set the policy with [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#work-item-policy).`"type":{"id":"40e92b44-2fe1-4dd6-b3d8-74a9c21d0c6e"}` this type id in the body below is by design.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/fabrikam-fiber-git/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=7.0`

```
Body
{"type":{"id":"40e92b44-2fe1-4dd6-b3d8-74a9c21d0c6e"}, 
"revision":1,
"isDeleted":false,
"isBlocking":true,
"isEnabled":true,
"settings":{
"scope":[{"repositoryId":"$(yourRepo)",
"refName":"refs/heads/$(yourBranch)",
"matchKind":"Exact"}]}}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the policy to check for linked work items only requires that work items are linked; it does not prevent merging until work items reach a certain state.

Comment: Your updated answer looks like a clever solution. I think there might be some awkward interactions where the build does not run automatically when work items are updated, but this should get the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no build-in feature to meet your requirements directly.

As a work around, for your scenario, I would suggest use Branch Policy [Check for comment resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#check-comment-resolution)

Enable this feature on your target branch.

[image]

Whoever creates the PR, ask him to leave a comment to check the related WIT to be resolved. The person who creates the PR could use "#" to mention the WIT

[image]

By checking the WIT to be resolved, PR approvers could resolve the comment to allow the merge.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this in a different way - the QA team was added as a required reviewer, which skips the need for making a special comment in this manner. Unfortunately the manual aspect of approval here is what we want to avoid. Ideally, the manual action that must be taken is that the work item is updated - the PR would automatically require this.